# Unix command "uniq" & "sort"

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, command, uniq

As we known

```
uniq [options] [file1 [file2]]
```

It remove duplicate adjacent lines from sorted file1. The option -c prints each line once, counting instances of each. So if we have the following result:

```
     34 Operating System
    254 Data Structure
      5 Crypo
     21 C++
   1435 C Language
    589 Java 1.6
```

And we sort above data using "sort -1knr", the result is as below:

```
   1435 C Language
    589 Java 1.6
    254 Data Structure
     34 Operating System
     21 C++
      5 Crypo
```

Can anyone help me out that how to output only the book name in this order (no number)?

Comment: `cut` is the magic word (one of them).

Comment: I think it will not work because there are several space in front of the number, how could you identify the field? Using "cut -d ' ' -f 2"? It will return nothing

Comment: For example "cut -c 9-", it will ignore the number, but we must know the exact number of characters in the count column

Comment: Yes, we need to know the width to use `cut`.

Comment: you mean `-k1nr`, not `-1knr`, right? also, thanks for the useful command!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uniq -c filename | sort -k 1nr | awk '{$1='';print}'
```

Comment: What about not using "awk" command? Only use "uniq", "sort", "tr", "wc", "head", "tail"

Comment: You already explained why `cut` is no good in your comment to Michael Krelin. You could use the `-c` option, but I wouldn't like to depend on the exact number of characters in the count column.

Comment: `cut` isn't no good, but it's the simplest way. I find this solution fine and tool appropriate. Of course you can do something with `while` and `read`, but really, `awk` is exactly the right tool for the task.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed` for that, as follows:

```
uniq -c filename | sort -k -1nr | sed 's/[0-9]\+ \(.\+\)/\1/g'
```

Test:

```
echo "34 Data Structure" | sed 's/[0-9]\+ \(.\+\)/\1/g'
Data Structure
```

This can also be done with a simplified regex (courtesy William Pursell):

```
echo "34 Data Structure" | sed 's/[0-9]* *//'
Data Structure
```

Comment: This could be greatly simplified: `sed 's/[0-9]* *//g'`

Comment: Indeed!, although the one you posted (with *) did not work in my tests, it worked with + , I'm adding that to my answer, thanks :-)

Comment: You cannot have the `g` flag in the simplified version.  That would munge titles like "20000 leagues under the sea".  (My error in including it; muscle memory dies hard.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `uniq -c` to print the number of occurences, which you then want to remove with some cut/awk/sed dance?

Instead , you could just use

```
sort -u $file1 $file2 /path/to/more_files_to_glob*
```

Or do some systems come with a version of `sort` which doesn't support `-u` ?